# Moving my Django project on DreamHost (error importing passenger_wsgi.py)

Tags: django, passenger, wsgi, dreamhost

I am trying to move my Django project to DreamHost.
I have created a virtualenv copied my project into the virtualenv on DreamHost server and installed all the dependency.

I created a passenger_wsgi.py file

```
import sys, os
cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
sys.path.append('/home/user/site/app_name')
sys.path.append('/home/user/site/project_name')
sys.path.append('/home/user/python/bin/')
sys.path.append('/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/home/user/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django')


#Swithch to new Python
INTERP = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], 'python', 'bin', 'python')
if sys.executable != INTERP:os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

When I try to visit my site through the browser I get a error:

Getting an internal server error (500)
error.logs 
Premature end of script headers: admin
Premature end of script headers: internal_error.html

access.logs
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 687 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36"